# Can't get bash script to run, getting errors

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run the script found here: http://blog.sebflipper.co.uk/2010/03/10/mysql-backup-as-separate-sql-files-with-rotation/comment-page-1/

`bash /path/to/mysql-backup.sh`

I'm getting the following errors:

```
/path/to/mysql-backup.sh: line 2:
: command not found
/path/to/mysql-backup.sh: line 4:
: command not found
/path/to/mysql-backup.sh: line 8:
: command not found
/path/to/mysql-backup.sh: line 10:
: command not found
/path/to/mysql-backup.sh: line 40: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'
/path/to/mysql-backup.sh: line 40: `function checkMysqlUp() {
```

Am I calling this command improperly?

Ok, it was the spaces, now I'm just getting the last 2 errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#! /bin/bash`

This line at the top of the script isn't right. It should have no spaces.

Comment: Once upon a long time ago, rumour had it that the space was necessary, and the kernel (or was it the shell?) looked at the first four bytes of the file for `#! /`, which acted as a magic number of sorts.  I think that is just an ill-founded rumour (a 2-byte magic number is plausible).  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on the subject.

Comment: Never knew that the space was once at least optional. That article is not at all clear on the required format, but the 1980 example clearly has a space. Huh.

Answer (score 5):

Given the way the error messages are appearing, I think you downloaded the script with CRLF line endings and the shell is not liking this.

Use 'dos2unix' or 'dtou' or (if neither of the above is available, `tr`) to remove the carriage returns.

```
tr -d '\015' < /path/to/mysql-backup.sh > /path/to/other-mysql-backup.sh
```

Then try running:

```
/path/to/other-mysql-backup.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not liking the blank lines in there. Are you sure when you maybe copied and pasted that you didn't inject ^M (carriage returns) or some other white-space character in there?

Comment: Great minds think alike - of course, it helps having a good first name, too.